# Can anyone help identify this grapevine?

Tags: identification

A bit of background, this is a vine growing in my garden in Surrey in the UK. I'm not sure of the variety and have tried to identify it through looking at photos online and the closest to the leaf I can see is zinfandel. I would appreciate any suggestions or help from anyone who knows these plants better than me! Many thanks, Rob. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your best chance is to identify the grapes when they ripen.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post again once they do.

Comment: In the words of Mr. Data in the common room of the Enterprise, when asked to identify a strange glass of liquid the response was "It is green." Time will give more info. It's a very healthy looking vine and bunch of fruit. Since the green of the leaf is not shiny we can rule out Vitis riparia as a species.